# Rules condition to check if user is a member of a specific group type?

Tags: rules

I'm trying to create a rule where the condition is that the currently logged in user is a member of a specific type of group. Can anyone offer assistance on the proper data selectors to use to build this condition?

For example, we have three types of groups:

Group Type 1
Group Type 2
Group Type 3

The condition, upon login, should be to check if the logged in user is an active member of Group Type 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what action should be taken then? Maybe it's a context where rules are not the optimal tool.

Answer (score 0):

The is a rule action "Rules has role" this should do it.